# I made a list of my class. How do i access that class by index?

Tags: c#, list

Heres my code:

```
namespace Visual_Debugger_Beta
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            label1.Text = "Input Modules (" + Input_Hierarchy.Items.Count + " Items)";
            label2.Text = "Output Modules (" + Output_Hierarchy.Items.Count + " Items)";
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void openImageToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Open Image and put it to Image box.
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.Filter = "png (*.png)|*.png|jpg (*.jpg)|*.jpg|bmp (*.bmp)|*.bmp";

            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK && ofd.FileName.Length > 0)
            {
                pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
                pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(ofd.FileName);
            }
        }

        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void projectToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //New Project
            pictureBox1.Image = null;
        }

        private void inputToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Add Input
            Input_Hierarchy.Items.Add(new mod_input(false, true));
            label1.Text = "Input Modules (" + Input_Hierarchy.Items.Count + " Items)";
        }

        private void outputToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Add Output
            Output_Hierarchy.Items.Add(new mod_output(false, true));
            label2.Text = "Output Modules (" + Output_Hierarchy.Items.Count + " Items)";
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Input_Hierarchy.Items.Clear();
            label1.Text = "Input Modules (" + Input_Hierarchy.Items.Count + " Items)";
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Output_Hierarchy.Items.Clear();
            label2.Text = "Output Modules (" + Output_Hierarchy.Items.Count + " Items)";
        }

        public void eventsUpdate()
        {
            bool a;
            bool t;
            a = Input_Hierarchy.SelectedItem.getIsActive();

        }
    }

    public class mod_input
    {
        public static bool isactive = false;
        public static bool toggle = true;

        public bool getIsActive()
        {
            return isactive;
        }

        public bool getToggle()
        {
            return toggle;
        }

        public mod_input(bool a, bool t)
        {
            isactive = a;
            toggle = t;
        }
    }

    public class mod_output
    {
        public bool isactive = false;
        public bool toggle = true;

        public mod_output(bool a, bool t)
        {
            isactive = a;
            toggle = t;
        }
    }
}
```

now, i have one error, and that is that it doesn't find the getIsActive() which i did code. I know this takes 5min to solve but i just cant.

Comment: Where is the error happening? Please don't just throw a ton of code up and say its broken. Which line is generating the error?

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this

```
var a =Input_Hierarchy.SelectedItem != null ?
    ((mod_input)Input_Hierarchy.SelectedItem).getIsActive() : false
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the SelectedItem property exposes the items as Objects since it isn't a generic list.  You need to cast to your class type before trying to access the property:

```
bool a;
bool t;
mod_input input = Input_Hierarchy.SelectedItem as mod_input;
a = input != null && input.getIsActive();
```

Comment: Now one final question (sorry for bothering you) how would i set a t? I made a function called updateEvents(bool a, bool t) and now in this i wanna set it. so i made two set methods in the mod_input, now how would i set it up now?